# Youtube stream embed - black bar on the right side

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, embed

I'm trying to embed a youtube stream, and it looks good with the video thumbnail and regular videos. However, when it comes to livestreams, a black bar appears on the right side of the video (and occasionally on the bottom as well).

Codepen: https://codepen.io/pbalsys/pen/MWoZQGb

Code:

```css
.thumbnail {
  width: 736px;
}
.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="video-wrapper">
    <iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCSJ4gkVC6NrvII8umztf0Ow" frameborder="0"  />
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems to depend on the resolution of the iframe, but I can't quite figure out the reason behind it: works on various resolutions when the `.thumbnail` width is up to 720px

[image: width = 720px]

But in higher resolutions, the black bar appears (width: 736px in this instance). Note that the thumbnail does not have the bar, but it shows up when the stream is played.

[image: width = 736px]

Later on, it disappears again when the width is 1104px.

The issue is also not as prevalent on different display resolutions - I cannot see the bar on my Macbook 16-inch (3072x1920), while it appears on my external display (2560x1440).

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: I've looked at this a few times now. Doesn't seem to be anything in the code and the fact that I can only get that black bar to display when the video is playing probably means there was an issue with the embedding itself (solution #1: re-embed). The other possibility is that that black bar is part of the video it self. However, I am still unsure. I was able to get the black right bar gone using width: 705px: but it seems anything past that gives you the black bar. Thinking the black bar is because the width is farther than what it supports. (solution 2: use % or vw to set width).

Comment: @Kameron Thank you for the tips, I'll look into re-embedding. As for solution 2, the original code was actually done with vw units, and I thought that the black bar was caused by imprecise pixel calculations; regardless, vw does not seem to solve the issue unfortunately.